# Creating complex json in php

Tags: php, json

I want to create a json array like below  using array , in php .

```
{   "1": [
    {
      "user_id": "1",
      "first_name": "akash"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "2",
      "first_name": "deepak"
    }   ],   "2": [
    {
      "user_id": "2",
      "first_name": "neeru"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "3",
      "first_name": "sumit"
    }   ] }
```

Comment: use `json_encode(your_array)` if you already have an array

Comment: @deepak I think you have to learn  about arrays first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
// your array here
$name_of_your_array=    array (
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'user_id' => '1',
      'first_name' => 'akash',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'user_id' => '2',
      'first_name' => 'deepak',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'user_id' => '2',
      'first_name' => 'neeru',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'user_id' => '3',
      'first_name' => 'sumit',
    ),
  ),
);

// json encode 
$json=json_encode($name_of_your_array);
print_r($json);
```

If you already have the json decoded data use json_decode function to get the array back or use some online tools like http://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode

Answer (score 0):

Assign your array to `json_encode` function like
Suppose your array is `$arr` 
`json_encode($arr);`
this function will convert you array in `json`.

Comment: Hi @user1374650 . I have to create above json using php array . but i am not able to create required array . Can you plz tell me how should i create array for this json .Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array('1'=>"Apple",'2'=> "Mango");

$jsonResult = json_encode($myArray);
```

Result:

```
{ "1": 
    [ 
        { "1": "Apple", "2": "Mango" }
    ]
}
```